# How to overlap color figure on a gray one with colorbar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to color code some parameter values on a gray image in MATLAB. I'm wondering how to show gray image, make parameter values colored on the gray appearance image and on some pixels, and finally draw a `colorbar` aside the image just showing parameter values range.

### Unsuccessful Code since now:

```
I = Igray; % gray image
Icc = zeros(size(I,1),size(I,2),3); % color coded image
Icc(:,:,1) = I;
Icc(:,:,2) = I;
Icc(:,:,3) = I;
Icc('some address in the image',3) = 'some number between 0 and 255';
imshow(Icc,[])
colorbar % colorbar showing colored parts spectrum
```

### Result image that I need:

[image]

Comment: Please include some code to show your progress and so we can reproduce what you're trying to do.

Comment: @verbatross here it is.

Comment: What is `Igray` and what kind of "color code" do you want?

Comment: maybe an image that looks like the one you want will make this clearer

Comment: @Yvon it is whatever gray image in the background and Icc is the rgb colored image in the foreground

Comment: @bla This is the resulting image I need

Comment: First of all, you can replace lines 2-5 with: `ICC = repmat(I,[1 1 3]);`

After that, I believe the accepted answer below should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16185953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
I = Igray; % gray image
RGB = [1.0,0.7,0.2]; % color for patch
x = 30:50;
y = 70:90;
% If you gray image is in the range [0,255], make it range [0,1]
I = double(I)/255;
Icc = repmat(I,[1,1,3]);
block = I(y,x);
Icc(y,x,1) = 1 - ((1-block) * (1-RGB(1)));
Icc(y,x,2) = 1 - ((1-block) * (1-RGB(2)));
Icc(y,x,3) = 1 - ((1-block) * (1-RGB(3)));
imshow(Icc)
```

I'm sure there is a prettier way to encode this, but this way it shows the intent.

You're basically multiplying the grey values with the RGB color you want to make the patch. By inverting the patch and the color first, and inverting the result, the multiplication makes the patch brighter, not darker. That way you get the effect you want where the dark parts show the color also. If you multiply directly without inverting first, black stays black and doesn't show the color.

You'll have to figure out how to coordinate with the color bar after that. There are commands in MATLAB to set the limits of the color bar, you can find those reading the documentation.

The color bar you show uses the PARULA color map. You could do this to find the right RGB value to color your patch:

```
T; % value to color your patch in, in range [0,1]
cm = parula(256);
RGB = interp1(cm,T*255,'linear')
```

Comment: There are two things I need to mention: first, each color (not gray value) has a meaning, for which I need `colorbar`. Second I need to omit gray values of gray image from `colorbar`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The `Icc` shown is a 3-channel image, it doesn't use a color map. Thus you can still set the figure's color map to be `parula`, and you can sample the colors from `parula` as I describe. This way you know exactly what value (color) you are making each patch, and these colors exactly match those in the color bar. The `T` above is the way to relate the color of the patch and the position along the color bar, which indicates what each color means.